# DB Table creation error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am new with android. First time inserting data to DB.

Code For Database table formation and insertion of data is as follows:

```
package com.example.hello_world;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class HNT {


    public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    public static final String KEY_FName="person_Fname";
    public static final String KEY_LName="person_Lname";

    private static final String Database_Name="DBPersonInfo";
    private static final String Database_Table="DBTable";
    private static final int Database_Version=1;        


    private DBHelper  ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDB;


    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, Database_Name, null, Database_Version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL( "create table "+Database_Table+ "("+
                    KEY_ROWID+"integer primary key autoincrement,"  +           
                    KEY_FName+"TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                    KEY_LName+"TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("drop table if exists"+ Database_Table );
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public HNT (Context c)
    {
        ourContext=c;

    }

    public HNT open() throws SQLException
    {
        ourHelper=new DBHelper(ourContext);
        ourDB=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;    
    }

    public void close()
    {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String fName, String lName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_FName, fName);
        cv.put(KEY_LName, lName);

        return ourDB.insert(Database_Table, null, cv);




    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_FName,KEY_LName};

        Cursor c=ourDB.query(Database_Table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result="";

        int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iFName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FName);
        int iLName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LName);

        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            result=result+c.getString(iRow)+ " " + c.getString(iFName)+ " " + c.getString(iLName)+ "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Its showing me error on logcat that no column exists person_Fname.

Logcat is as follows:

[image]

Please help me.

Its not letting me insert data. (Basically table formation error).

Is my syntax or method for table formation or insertion has gone wrong?

EDIT:

I edited table creation part, included spaces in it:

```
db.execSQL( "create table "+Database_Table+ "("+
                    KEY_ROWID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"  +           
                    KEY_FName+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                    KEY_LName+" TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

But it given me same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing spaces in your DB creation. Change:

```
db.execSQL( "create table "+Database_Table+ "("+
                    KEY_ROWID+"integer primary key autoincrement,"  +           
                    KEY_FName+"TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                    KEY_LName+"TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

to

```
db.execSQL( "create table "+Database_Table+ "("+
                    KEY_ROWID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"  +           
                    KEY_FName+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                    KEY_LName+" TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

Also:

```
db.execSQL("drop table if exists"+ Database_Table );
```

to:

`db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+ Database_Table );`

Comment: which spaces are necessary?

Comment: yes, if you have KEY_ROWID="_id" for example, your creation is:  `_idinteger primary key autoincrement,` which will create a different column name

Comment: I just copy and pasted ur code which include all the spaces, but its showing me same error

Comment: You need to uninstall the App as this will run only when creating the DB

Comment: No, You need to remove the App from the Emulator/Test phone to delete the DB from its File system and then when you run it again, it will reinstall and recreate the DB correctly

Comment: i am in data/data/database/dbName,,,trying to delete db....but not able to delete it

Comment: Simply remove the App from Application Manager and it will delete all the file system

Comment: plz help,, i m new with this, and in trouble

Comment: You code is on your development PC. When you run the App, Eclipse (or any other environment) will package your code to an .apk file and install it on the test device/Emulator. It is like when you uninstall an App from your phone, you get the APK again from the market.

Comment: Go to settings on your phone/Emulator -> Application Manager -> Search for your App -> Choose uninstall. Then on Eclipse, choose run again, it will reinstall the App on your Emulator/phone and will recreate the DB

Comment: i simply changed my name of db and table,,, and it worked...thanx a lot for ur help.

Comment: enjoy 3k + ...congrats

Answer (score 1):

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
Context mContext;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Personal_Assistant_Chronical.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_DETAIL = "newContact";

private static final String COLUMN_PERSON_ID= "personID";
private static final String COLUMN_PERSON_NAME= "person_name";
private static final String COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_no";
private static final String COLUMN_LANDLINE_NUMBER = "lanline_no";
private static final String COLUMN_FAX_NUMBER = "fax_no";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL_ID = "email_id";
private static final String COLUMN_PERSONAL_ADDRESS = "personal_address";
private static final String COLUMN_WORK_ADDRESS = "work_address";

private static final String CREATE_DETAIL_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
        + TABLE_DETAIL
        + "("
        + COLUMN_PERSON_ID
        +" INTEGER primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_PERSON_NAME
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
        + COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , "
        + COLUMN_LANDLINE_NUMBER
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_FAX_NUMBER
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_EMAIL_ID
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_PERSONAL_ADDRESS
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_WORK_ADDRESS
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL); "
        ;
private static final String TABLE_PERSONAL = "newPersonal";

private static final String COLUMN_DATE_ID= "dateID";
private static final String COLUMN_DATE= "fate";
private static final String COLUMN_DIARY= "diary";

private static final String CREATE_PERSONAL_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
        + TABLE_PERSONAL
        + "("
        + COLUMN_DATE_ID
        +" INTEGER primary key autoincrement , "
        + COLUMN_DATE
        +" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
        + COLUMN_DIARY
        + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL); "

        ;   


public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DETAIL_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PERSONAL_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if (db != null)
        onCreate(db);
}
```

Just create the database and table like this it will running sucessfully .....as am i trying.just giving permission in manifest file...for Access_EXTERNAL_STORAGE